# Eclipse → AndroidStudio: Where can I see my errors?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, ide

I'm trying to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio. There are a few things that bug me, but one stands out:

**Q1:** Is there no way to do automatic builds and have a list of problems displayed immediately like in Eclipse?

I know, there are many refactoring tools, but my often-used practise is to just insert a character into the name of a method and variable and check problems-view to see where it's being used.

**Q2:** How can replace or replicate this workflow in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is deactivate the external build. To do so click on "compiler settings icon" in the "Messages Make" panel that appears when you have an error. You can also open the compiler settings by going to File -> Settings -> Compiler. (Thanx to @maxgalbu for this tip).

enter image description here

Uncheck "Use External build"

enter image description here

And you will see the errors in the console

EDIT: After returning to "internal build" again you may get some errors, you can solve them this way: Android Studio: disabling "External build" to display error output create duplicate class errors

Comment: I don't see any option called "External build" in my Android Studio 1.5 on OSX.